# Deploying communities using package.xml

Tags: deployment, salesforce-communities

I am trying to retrieve Salesforce communities names 'XXX Community' from one org into VS Code and subsequently want to deploy it into another org.

However, when I use the `sfdx force:source:retrieve -u DemoMaster -x ./package.xml` command, for the below package.xml file, I get the following error:

> Entity of type 'CustomSite' named 'XXX_Community_Test' cannot be found
>   Entity of type 'SiteDotCom' named 'XXX_Community_Test1' cannot be found

Only the network and network branding elements got retrieved.

The package.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"> 
    <types>
        <members>XXX Community</members>
        <name>Network</name>
     </types>
     <types>
        <members>XXX_Community_Test</members>
        <name>CustomSite</name>
     </types>
     <types>
        <members>XXX Community_Test1</members>
        <name>SiteDotCom</name>
     </types>
     <types>
        <members>cbXXX_Community</members>
        <name>NetworkBranding</name>
    </types> 
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Any help appreciated!
D